# C++ using union to set 64bit variable and read 2 32bits

Tags: c++, struct, unions

`

```
union {
    uint64_t    entryid;
    uint32_t    entryid[2];
};

entryid = get64bitKey();

storeKeytodb(entryid[0],entryid[1]);
.........
getKeyFromDB(&entrid[0], &entryid[1]);
```

`

Do you guys see any issue with this if this is set/get stored/read on same host (same endianness)

Is below a better way of doing this

`

```
union {
    uint64_t    entryid;
    struct {
    uint32_t    entryid1;
    uint32_t    entryid2;
    }entry;

};
```

`

Comment: Your two examples do completely different things. Both are illegal in C++.

Comment: completely my bad. Was writing a pseudo code to put across my question and completely messed up the code. Edited the code to what I intend to write

Can someone answer it now

Comment: Ah common! -2 votes for not framing the question right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do that is simply this:

```
uint64_t value = ...
uint32_t highword = static_cast<uint32_t>(value >> 32);
uint32_t lowword = static_cast<uint32_t>(value);
```

The revers (which you didn't explicitly ask for but which your code seems to suggest) is this:

```
uint32_t highword = ...
uint32_t lowword = ...
uint64_t value = (static_cast<uint64_t>(highword) << 32) + lowword;
```

Note that here, it is important to first convert the highword and then to shift it.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich. Out of curiosity, what's the issue with my first approach? Apart from endianness

Comment: Furstly, neither of the two `union` approaches is necessary. Then, both your approaches rely on things that are specifically labelled as "undefined behaviour" I believe, because you may only read from that member of a union that you wrote to, with an exception for structs with equal first members. Your second approach further adds possible padding between the struct members to the list of issues.

Comment: Thank you for giving the explanation I was looking for